# Inverse of $A^\top BA+C^\top DC$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-methods

I'm numerically solving a system of equations of the form:

$$Mx = b$$

where:

$$M = A^\top BA+C^\top DC,$$
$B$ and $D$ are block-diagonal, 
$A$ and $C$ are $n\times m$ matrices with $m \leq n+3$.

Are there any theorems in the spirit of the matrix inversion lemma that I could exploit to find the inverse of $M$ more cheaply than the obvious way?